# Spreading data for one tenant to multiple shards in Solr

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud

I am trying to set up a sharded set up for Solr.
My index file size is 100 GB and increasing.
Data distribution is across 32 tenant where each tenant has different count of document:
Tenant 1 : 7 M
Tenant 2 : 3 M
Tenant 3 : 3 M
Tenant 4 : 2 M
Tenant 5-28 : 6 M (combined)

So i was trying to use bit operation in shard key like this :
tenant/2!uniqueId

I have one query here if I have 5 shards in total then how this bit num 2 will spread data.
I want to spread data for one tenant to 2 shards.

Could you please help me to identify minim number of shards in this set up to achieve this.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal